# Wordpress RewriteRule is not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current .htaccess file content:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

I want to change:

```
http://example.com/search/?location=&radius_key=sydney/&keyword=&geolocation=
```

to:

```
http://example.com/massage/sydney/
```

I have modified script as below but it's not changing my URL. Could you please guide me. Any kind of response to fix this problem is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/massage/(.*)$ /search/? location=&radius_key=$1&keyword=&geolocation=
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL displayed in the browser address bar to change, you have to activate the "R" flag in modrewrite, which activate the Redirection.

So you'll write something like

```
RewriteRule /search/\?.*location=([a-z0-9_.-]+)&.* geolocation=$1 [R=301,L]
```

I suggest also to split the configuration in two part, in order to keep the original Wordpress configuration unmodified.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /search/\?.*location=([a-z0-9_.-]+)&.* geolocation=$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I used your code and did hit (http://example.com/search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=).
Page is showing "Internal Server Error".

Comment: I've edited the code, now it should work better. Keep in mind that I've just rearranged the code you provided, and it should be tuned.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this?
RewriteRule ^/massage/(.*)$ /search/\?.*location=([a-z0-9_.-]+)&.* geolocation=$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change up your rules a little bit. This should allow you to use the new URL and also your wordpress rules.

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /search/\?location=&radius_key=([^\ &]+)&keyword=&geolocation=
 RewriteRule ^ /massage/%1? [R=301,L]

 RewriteRule ^massage/([^/]+)/?$ /search/?location=&radius_key=$1&keyword=&geolocation= [L]

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Thank Panama. I used your code and did hit (http://example.com/search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=).
No change showed. Same URL (http://example.com/search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=) loaded again.

Comment: I made it so you can use `http://example.com/massage/sydney/` in the browser not, the other way around. However I changed it to work with both.Please check my updated answer for what you are requesting now.

Comment: Thanks Panama. I used above code.
When search directs to the page (search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=). It's not showing this URL that's fine but problem is that now it's not taking me to the content of a page that's shown on (search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=). Now Page is being taken to a new page that is : (listing/sydney_acupuncture_and_massage_cbd/). Not the page, I'm searching for and the url I'm searching for (massage/sydney/) :(

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Does it redirect using the query string URL now? And if so where is it redirecting to. It should be redirecting to `/massage/somethinghere/`

Comment: Thanks Panama. I don't want to redirect (example.com/search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=) to (/massage/sydney/) rather I want to keep showing the content of same page(search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=) but user should be seeing this url(http://example.com/massage/sydney/).

Comment: That's what it does. If they type in `http://example.com/massage/sydney` it should show whatever content this is by using the 3rd rewrite rule. But if they type in `http://example.com/search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=` it will send them back to the correct URL of `http://example.com/massage/sydney` and display the content. It's supposed to work that way.

Comment: But unfortunately, it not only changes the URL but also the content of the page that shouldn't be changed. Content of a page(massage/sydney/ should be the same as of (search/?location=&radius_key=sydney&keyword=&geolocation=). Just URL should be changed, not content of the page.

Comment: Something else is wrong then. The rules don't have anything to do with the content. It just handles the URL's. You need to check your code and print out what is being sent with each URL. So do a `print_r($_GET);` or something you navigating each URL to see what values are being sent.